# Draggable Material UI tabs

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, material-ui

I am looking for a solution for being able to drag and drop Material UI tabs which would change their order in the tabs, just like you can change tab order in a browser when you have multiple tabs open by dragging and dropping them into different positions. I haven't seen much online in specifics to material ui tabs. Curious if anyone has a solution before I go and try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The **Material UI Tab API** doesn't have and option to `drag` and `drop` the Tabs. But you can develop this functionality using the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API):

This is a basic example:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  const tabList = ev.target.closest("div[role='tablist']"); 
  let node = ev.target.getAttribute("role") === "tab" ? ev.target : ev.target.closest('[role="tab"]');
  tabList.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), node.nextSibling);
}

return (<Tabs
         value={value}
         onChange={handleChange}
         aria-label="simple tabs example"
        >
         <Tab
           label="Item One"
           onDrop={drop}
           onDragOver={allowDrop}
           draggable="true"
           onDragStart={drag}
         />
         ...   
       </Tabs>)
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jl9yj)

Comment: I appreciate the example, as far as I can tell this doesn't really work. Dragging item one to item's two position will place it at item 3's position, or it sometimes it won't place it at all, seems to be inconsistent working with these tabs.

Comment: Yes, it is just an example, that is because the element is inserted using tabList.insertBefore(document.getElementById(data), node); very basic, but you can change the way (before, after) you insert the draggable item